# ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/App.tsx:1:8

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, build

Well i'm just trying to make simple react app with the walletconnect functionality. but i'm getting
bunch of errors, can you guys please show some support and help me to resolve these errors.

**traceback.**

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/App.tsx:1:8 
    TS1259: Module '"C:/Users/AHMED/Downloads/Webpack-React-Setup-master/Webpack-React-Setup-master/node_modules/@types/react/index"' can only be default-imported using the 'esModuleInterop' flag

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/App.tsx:10:10 
    TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'App'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/App.tsx:45:12 
    TS2339: Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'App'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/App.tsx:46:24 
    TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'App'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/App.tsx:47:18 
    TS2339: Property 'state' does not exist on type 'App'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/components/index.tsx:10:5 
    TS2605: JSX element type 'App' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
  Type 'App' is missing the following properties from type 'ElementClass': context, setState, forceUpdate, props, and 2 more.
i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

**index.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

**App.tsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import WalletConnect from "@walletconnect/client";
import QRCodeModal from "@walletconnect/qrcode-modal";


class App extends React.Component<any, any> {

  constructor(props:any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      address: ''

    }
    var connector = new WalletConnect({
      bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", // Required
      qrcodeModal: QRCodeModal,
    });
  }

  walletConnectFunc = async () => {
    var connector = new WalletConnect({
      bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", // Required
      qrcodeModal: QRCodeModal,
    });
    if (connector.connected) {
      alert("already connected")
      return
    }
    connector.createSession();
    connector.on("connect", async (error, payload) => {
      console.log("connect")
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      // Get provided accounts and chainId
      const { accounts, chainId } = payload.params[0];
      console.log("connect account", accounts)
      console.log("chainid account", chainId)

      const obj = {
        "address": accounts[0],

      }
      this.setState({ address: obj.address })
      console.log(this.state.address)
      alert(this.state.address)
    })


  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <body>
          <div>
            <button className="btn btn-primary my-4" type="button" onClick={() => this.walletConnectFunc()}>WalletConnect</button>
          </div>
        </body>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have an app in another project with name App.js. And I just want to use the same code but in App.tsx file with type script syntax. I'm problem making bunch of mistakes. You can guys fix it out. I have no knowing of typescript.

Just for referencing (App.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './App.css';
import WalletConnect from "@walletconnect/client";
import QRCodeModal from "@walletconnect/qrcode-modal";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      address: ''

    }
    this.connector = new WalletConnect({
      bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", // Required
      qrcodeModal: QRCodeModal,
    });
  }


  walletConnectFunc = async () => {

    if (this.connector.connected) {
      alert("already connected")
      return
    }
    this.connector.createSession();
    this.connector.on("connect", async (error, payload) => {
      console.log("connect")
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }

      // Get provided accounts and chainId
      const { accounts, chainId } = payload.params[0];
      console.log("connect account", accounts)
      console.log("chainid account", chainId)

      const obj = {
        "address": accounts[0],

      }
      this.setState({ address: obj.address })
      console.log(this.state.address)
      alert(this.state.address)
    })


  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <body>
          <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-4" type="button" onClick={() => this.walletConnectFunc()}>WalletConnect</button>
          </div>
        </body>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

if more code is require then tell me in a comment section. I'll update my question with that information. thank you so much.

Comment: So it looks like you're using Typescript, and these are Type errors - do you have the typings for React installed? `npm i @types/react`

Comment: @jnotelddim done now. but traceback is still same

Comment: couple more questions: 1) how did you create the project? 2) how are you running the app?

Comment: Also, this is kind of aside the point, but if you're just doing this as an exercise to learn Typescript -- I'd recommend you start with a typescript tutorial.

Comment: well i downloaded this [link]https://github.com/krofax/Webpack-React-Setup  react project with already webpack configuration and trying to convert my old App.js file into App.tsx file so i can use that in this project.

Comment: @jnotelddim actually i'm working under a company . I am creating website and in that website i have to implement walletconnect functionality.

Comment: I'd suggest you start a fresh project with `create-react-app` ( https://create-react-app.dev/ ). They've got a `--typescript` flag I think which you can use to generate a Typescript React project. And CRA uses webpack in its configuration. It might be cleaner to just do it that way instead of basing your project on someone else's (when it's not guaranteed to be in a functional state or anything, and you never know how well they're maintaining that Webpack-React-Setup repo)

Comment: @jnotelddim I dont need to learn typescript for now cause i haven't this much time to learn any new thing

Comment: Ah ok -- well if you don't want to learn typescript, I'd recommend that you don't use Typescript files, and instead just use the Javascript files which are already working :P

Comment: Wallectconnect package is itself written in typescript thats the issue

Comment: I've linked CRA above, but here it is again: https://create-react-app.dev/

Comment: Sorry is `walletconnect` an npm package? if you're trying to use a TS npm package in a JS project, it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: As i told you i'm using someones code in which he just configurate all webpack stuff. Now the point is i dont want to mess up anything from that code except App.tsx . So Can you do me a small favor. As you can see I gave App.js code as well as App.tsx code . Can you convert my app.js code into App.tsx code . I believe that thing can fix my problem.

Comment: I'm sure there are many many contractors out there who would be happy to help you for a small fee.

Comment: umm yeah sure, thanks anyway :)